# How to fix: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

Tags: python, vba

I am trying to control CST Studio with Python by converting the VB scripts to Python. The code as follows:

```
import win32com.client
import comtypes
import win32com.client.gencache
import os
import os.path
import datetime

from CSTModel import DefaultUnits, DefineFrequencyRange, MeshInitiator, DefineBoundary, DefineBackGroundMaterial
cst = win32com.client.Dispatch("CSTStudio.Application")
mws= cst.NewMWS()
DefaultUnits(mws)
DefineFrequencyRange(mws,4,8)
```

This is the DefaultUnits(mws) and DefineFrequencyRange(mws) in the CSTModel.py

```
    def DefaultUnits(mws):

# define default units (Default selection)
    Units = mws.Units
    Units.Geometry("um")
    Units.Frequency("GHz")
    Units.Time('ns')
    Units.TemperatureUnit('Kelvin')
    Units.Voltage('V')
    Units.Current('A')
    Units.Resistance('Ohm')
    Units.Conductance('S')
    Units.Capacitance('PikoF')
    Units.Inductance('NanoH')

# FREQUENCY RANGE----------------------------
def DefineFrequencyRange(mws,frange1,frange2):

# Define the simulated frequency range
    solver = mws.solver()
    solver.FrequencyRange(str(frange1),str(frange2))
    MeshSettings = mws.MeshSettings()
    MeshSettings.SetMeshType('Hex')
    MeshSettings.Set('Version','1%')
    Mesh = mws.Mesh()    
    Mesh.MeshType('PBA')
```

The CSTModel module I have created my own by converting VB scripts.
The DefaultUnits(mws) works fine. However, the DefineFrequencyRange(mws,4,8) cannot work and it comes with an errors as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Minh Tran\Desktop\pycst\Python2CST\CST.py", line 13, in <module>
    DefineFrequencyRange(mws,4,8)
  File "C:\Users\Minh Tran\Desktop\pycst\Python2CST\CSTModel.py", line 805, in DefineFrequencyRange
    solver = mws.solver()
  File "C:\Users\Minh Tran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

Is there anyone know the solutions or suggestions for this problem?
I will be grateful if you can help me out.